# How to launch any URL into Chrome Custom Tab as non-logged in

Tags: android, chrome-custom-tabs, android-customtabs

I have an android sample app where I want to open any URL into **Chrome Custom Tab** instead of **WebView**.
I am trying from https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/android/customtabs and able to do this.

Here I'm facing a problem and that is -

> If I already logged-in into facebook from **Chrome Browser**, then it is
>   also shown  as logged-in when I launch facebook url into **Chrome Custom
>   Tab**.

It seems like **Chrome Custom Tab** is using the cookies of **Chrome Browser**.
But I want to launch any URL into **Chrome Custom Tab** as "*non-logged-in*" state regardless the login state of **Chrome Browser**.

The problem is that I didn't find any way to clear cookies of chrome custom tab, although previously I cleared cookies by "cookieManager.removeAllCookie()" for webview.

*Is it possible to clear cookies of chrome custom tab before launch URL, can anyone please help to achieve this ?*

Here is my code to lauch URL into chrome custom tab -

```
private void launchURL(String url) {
    CustomTabsIntent.Builder builderCustomTabs = new CustomTabsIntent.Builder();
    CustomTabsIntent intentCustomTabs = builderCustomTabs.build();
    intentCustomTabs.intent.setPackage("com.android.chrome");
    intentCustomTabs.intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    intentCustomTabs.launchUrl(this, Uri.parse(url));
}
```

Comment: `launchUrl` method is not working in my code.

Answer (score 0):

I have done something like this with my own app. In my case, I used a URL which logs the user out and redirects to the login page.

After some research about Facebook logout URL, I find that it is possible only if you have the user token. The only way I thought you can manage this, is creating a web page to execute some JavaScript code (using Facebook SDK) to log the user out of Facebook, then you can redirect him to Facebook log in page. I never tested it, but maybe it will work.

Comment: I asked this in such a way that it seems like facebook specific question. By the way, I have updated as this question is not only for facebook. Sorry for the inconvenience and Thanks for your time.

Comment: Well...so you could customize chrome custom tab code. It is available o GitHub. What you think?

Comment: The problem is that for webview implementation I cleared cookie by 'cookieManager.removeAllCookie()' before loading url, but for chrome custom tab implementation I didn't find any way.